# Определении функции в C++

Tags: c++

Для чего нужен амперсанд в определении функции? А также const в самом названии функции, в аргументах все понятно что для чего, но конкретно с названием функции не до конца понимаю.

```
const string & version2(string & s1, const string & s2) 
{ 
    s1 = s2 + s1 + s2;
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: перед названием функции вы описываете возвращаемое значение, `const` и `&` относятся к возвращаемой строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const string & version2(string & s1, const string & s2) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  - Возвращаемый тип
               ^^^^^^^^ - имя функции
                        ^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - типы аргументов
```

Это функция `version2`, которая принимает ссылку на строку `s1`, ссылку на константную строку `s2` (т.е. обещает не менять `s2` по ходу работы), а возвращает - ссылку на константную строку, т.е. получив которую, вы не можете ее менять.

Answer (score 0):

1. Возвращать ссылку.
2. Возвращать константную ссылку.

Зачем надо - например, это позволяет не делать лишних копирований, а также гарантирует, что получивший такую ссылку не сможет в нее что-то записать.

Comment: Минусующим предлагаю написать, где я ошибся, инересно же.